# How to make Reveal height smaller than the viewport on mobile?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm working on a responsive site that has a Foundation Reveal modal on page load. I know the default for Reveal on SMALL screens is to take up the entire screen, but I need it to shrink so that the user can still see there is a website behind it.

I have been able to bring the sides in, and push the top down. No matter what I do to try to adjust the height or bring the bottom up, the modal is always just bigger than the viewport on mobile. I have not been able to find any solution to this issue.

I have tried using hard pixels and percents for height, min-height, max-height, and using padding on the reveal-overlay with no luck.

Here is the CSS I've used to bring the top and sides in:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
    .reveal {
        width: 80%;
        margin: auto;
        top: 10%;
    }
}
```

Ideally, there would be about 10% between both the top of the modal and the bottom of the modal to the top and bottom of the viewport, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The offset top is set with JS as a style on the modal. To override in CSS you'll need !important and vh units because a % is not relative to anything.

```
.reveal {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 15vh !important;
}
```

https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/eozgPV?editors=1100

Or change in JS

on the `.reveal` add `data-v-offset="150"`

`data-v-offset` -> number or string
Distance, in pixels, the modal should push down from the top of the screen.

To center the modal vertically, you can use the absolute center trick:

```
top: 50vh !important;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

You can also override the 100vh default height like this:

```
min-height: 85vh;
height: 85vh !important;
```

Example: https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/dLpbwZ?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you Rafi, that makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately, that doesn't help with the bottom of the modal. I had the top spaced, but the modal is still below the bottom of the screen on mobile. Is there a similar fix for getting the bottom to come up? Ideally, to fit the content.

Comment: Did you already try `max-height: calc(100vh - 15vh - bottomValue)` with `overflow-y:scroll`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, @DanielRuf, unfortunately it is still stretched all the way to the bottom of the screen! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you try it with `!important` and check the applied styles in the developer tools of your browser?